# Entity Framework is adding an extra foreign key to my table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a very simple data model: a bog standard 1:m relationship. But I want it slightly denormalised for performance reasons and the EF is not doing what I expect it to do.

I am getting an extra foreign key on a join table when I have a 1:m relationship and also slightly denormalise the data so that my `Product` table has a reference to a specific order as well as a list of orders.

Take 2 classes: `Customer` and `Product`. They have a m:m relationship, which is to be joined by the `Orders` class.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; } 
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

So far so simple. Everything is as I expect it to be with the table definitions:

Customers

```
CustomerId int
Name nvarchar(MAX)
```

Products

```
ProductId int
Name nvarchar(MAX)
```

Orders

```
OrderId int
Customer_CustomerId int
Product_ProductId int
```

Now the issue. For reasons I won't go into right now, I want to hold the latest order for a product on the product table itself, rather than have to query and do a `WHERE OrderId = MAX(OrderId)` on the `Orders` table.

So I change my model class by adding a single line:

```
public virtual Order MostRecentOrder { get; set; }
```

The DB definition for the `Product` table looks just as I would expect:

```
MostRecentOrder_OrderId int
```

However, EF has *also* added a foreign key to the `Orders` table:

```
Product_ProductId1 int
```

That shouldn't be there. Only one `Order` can be the LATEST order, and I have a single instance of the order in my `Product` class.

So I tried doing it a bit more explicitly in the `Product` class:

```
    public int MostRecentOrderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MostRecentOrderId")]
    public virtual Order MostRecentOrder { get; set; }
```

The `Product` field gets a name change to reflect the explicitly named column in my class, but the `Orders` table still has that extra foreign key to the `Product` table.

I kept playing and found that I could get rid of the erroneous foreign key on the `Orders` table by unmapping the `Product` class:

```
    public int? MostRecentOrderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MostRecentOrderId")]
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual Order MostRecentOrder { get; set; }
```

I also missed the nullable requirement in my prototype ;)

However, now I cannot make use of pre-loading the data.

This code:

```
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
var products = db.Products.Include("Orders").Include("MostRecentOrder").ToList();
```

throws this exception:

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'WebApplication1.Models.Product' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'MostRecentOrder'.

What am I missing here? I just wish the `Product` table to have a list of orders, *and* a reference to one (special) order. In traditional client/server dev, I would code this SQL to get the data back:

```
-- to go into the "Product" object
SELECT * 
FROM Products
LEFT JOIN Orders ON Products.MostRecentOrderId = Orders.OrderId;
WHERE ProductId = 4
```

and

```
-- to go into the "Product.Orders collection"
SELECT * 
FROM Orders 
WHERE ProductId = 4;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after you add the `MostRecentOrder` navigation property, the `Product` class would look like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual Order MostRecentOrder { get; set; }
}
```

What you can do next is use the Fluent API to configure the relationships inside your context class like this:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Order>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Product)
            .WithMany(x => x.Orders);

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Product>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.MostRecentOrder);
    }
}
```

It seems to me that convention based configuration are not explicit enough to tell EF about your relationships in such case. Fluent API is more explicit.